# Casting a string to float/decimal - big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Hoping someone can advise me on this. I have two tables in big query, the first is called master, the second is called daily_transfer.

In the master table, there is a column named **impression_share**, the data type is float and all working correctly.

However my problem is with the daily_transfer table. The idea is that on a daily basis, I'll transfer this data into **master**. The schema and column names are exactly the same in both tables. The problem however is that in the daily transfer table, in my float column (impression_share), I have a string value, which is **< 0.1**.

This string isn't pulled up as an issue initially as the table is being loaded from a google sheet, so the error is only highlighted when I try to query the data.

In summary, column type is float, but a recurring value is a string. I've tried a couple of things, firstly replacing the '< 0.1' to '0.1', but I get an error that replace can only be used with an expression of string, string, string. Which makes sense to me.

So I've tried to cast the column instead from float to string, and then replace the value. When I try to cast though I'm getting an error right away:

"Error while reading table: data-studio-reporting.analytics.daily_transfer, error message: Could not convert value to float. Row 3; Col 6."

Column 6 being "impression_share", row 3 value being < 0.1.

The query I was trying is:

```
SELECT 


SAFE_CAST(mydata.impression_share AS STRING)

FROM `data-studio-reporting.analytics.daily_transfer` mydata
```

I just don't know if its possible what I'm trying to do, or if I would be better recreating the daily_transfer table and setting column 6 (impression_share) as String, to make it easier to replace and then cast before I transfer to the main table?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: in daily transfer table the value is literally String "< 0.1" or there are numbers like "0.09", "0,08" etc. ? If it is String "< 0.1", can you change it to "0.09" or similiar number? the problem with conversion would be becouse of character "<"

Comment: It's a mix unfortunately, the majority of the values in that column are actually float values, 0.1, 0.25 etc. But around 10% of the values are string '< 0.1'.   I'm thinking (without a full understanding) it might be easier to recreate the daily_transfer table and change that column type to string?

Comment: Yo wrote earlier that in master table column impression_share the data type is float, and in daily_transfer it's string. You can change column type from float to String but it won't change the fact that the data will be basically useless. When it's Stringy ou can't sum, max, avg etc., The better solution would be to change "< 0.1" to number

Comment: Sorry I meant to say that in daily_transfer it is also float. I'm thinking the issue is that because of the column type and value mismatch I can't actually load the data to work on it? I.e if I was creating a table from a CSV, with the same parameters it would fail..  I'm away from computer bit will try changing column type, then replace the value as you said, then possibly cast to float before adding to my master_table. I will try this tomorrow, logically seems ok but again I may be wrong. Enjoying learning either way..

Comment: And also thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help on this, changing the column type in my daily_transfer_table from float to string, then replacing and casting has worked.

```
SELECT
mydata.Date,

CAST (REPLACE(mydata.Impression_share,'<','')  AS FLOAT64 ) as impression_share_final,
mydata.Available_impressions
 FROM `data-studio-reporting.google_analytics.daily_transfer_temp_test` mydata
```

been great for my knowledge to learn this one. thanks!